# In-order successor of a Binary Tree

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, tree, binary-tree

I was writing a code for finding the in-order successor for a binary tree ( NOT A BINARY SEARCH TREE ). It's just a practice problem . More like to brush up tree concepts.

I was doing an in-order traversal and keeping track of the previous node . Whenever the previous node becomes equal to the node whose successor we are searching for , I print the current node .

```
void inOrder(node* root , node* successorFor) {
  static node* prev = null;
  if(!root)
     return;
  inOrder(root->left,successorFor);
  if(prev == successorFor )
     print(root);
  prev = root;
  inOrder(root->right,successorFor);
}
```

I was looking for some test cases where my solution might fail ? And whether my approach is correct or not ? If it's not , then how should i go about it ?

Comment: Where is `prev` defined?

Comment: I believe the algorithm is right, but does it make sense to print successorFor? Or you're to print root in fact?

Comment: @DavidB Done. it is a static variable.

Comment: @Marcus Yes , just a typo , it is root only. I will edit.

Comment: Is this C++ or C or Java? It's not all three.

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic of this algorithm is a `tree walk`.
You make a call like `print(TREE-SUCCESSOR(root, k).key)`

```
TREE-SUCCESSOR(root, k)
    if root == NIL
        return NIL
    left = TREE-SUCCESSOR(root.left, k)
    right = TREE-SUCCESSOR(root.right, k)
    successor = NIL
    if root.key > k
        successor = root
    if left
        if k < left.key
            if successor
                if left.key < successor.key
                    successor = left
            else
                successor = left
    if right
        if k < right.key
            if successor
                if right.key < successor.key
                    successor = right
            else
                successor = right
    return successor
```

Comment: It is just a binary tree , and I need to find the next inorder successor of  a node , that is , the next node that i would get during the tree walk after that given node.

Comment: This algorithm doesn't assume anything about the position of the successor, that is why there is a recursive call to the left child and also to the right child.